# Cartographer SLAM - TF Tree Errors

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, cartographer, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am completely stuck on a tf problem.
What I try to do is slam with a laser sensor and an imu with cartographer_ros.
According to the related tutorial, I define my physical layout of the robot in a urdf file:

> 

>           

>        
> 
>   
>     
>       
>       
>         
>       
>       
>        
> 
>   
>     
>       
>       
>         
>       
>       
>        
> 
>   
> 
>    type="fixed">
>     
>     
>        
>
>    type="fixed">
>     
>     
>        
> 
>

This file clearly defines the transformation between base_link and imu_link as well as base_link with base_laser_link.
Than I call cartographer to do slam which is calling state_publisher.
However, cartographer shows an error that it cannot relate the imu_link to the base_link.
Also in tf viewer in rqt it is visible, that imu_link and base_link are not connected via a transformation, while base_link and base_laser_link are connected without problems. Did anyone of you have a similar issue?
Why doe the state_publisher not relate the imu_link with the base_link?

*** Update ***

The TF tree appears to be constructed correctly just using the robot state publisher.
This means the base_link is parent to imu_link and base_laser_link.
However, as soon as I start cartographer_ros node the tf tree is ripped apart.
Then it shows the new topic odom (which shall be generated by the slam)
which is parent to imu_link. Separatly (unconnected) to this also we still have the base_link topic which is parent to "base_laser_link".
The error the cartographer is throwing is:

```
"Could not find a connection between 'imu_link' and 'base_laser_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
```

Before starting cartographer
[image: Before starting cartographer]
After starting cartographer:
[image: After starting cartographer]

*** Update ***
I could further break down the error, that the imu manager is causing this tf fault.
The imu is based one the phidget imu package:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-phidgets-imu
```

Which is called with the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="imu_manager" 
    args="manager" output="screen" />

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="PhidgetsImuNodelet" 
    args="load phidgets_imu/PhidgetsImuNodelet imu_manager" 
    output="screen">
    <param name="period" value="4"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="imu_link"/> 
  </node>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="ImuFilterNodelet" 
    args="load imu_filter_madgwick/ImuFilterNodelet imu_manager" 
    output="screen">

    <param name="use_mag" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_magnetic_field_msg" value="true"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

However, I cannot find out why this imu manager is creating a tf connection between frame /odom and /imu_link and at the same time breaking /imu_link and /base_link. Do you have any idea?

*** Update ***
The velocity filter of the imu package has been using a tf tree for the filtering.
By only using the raw imu data the problem has been resolved.

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316747/cartographer-slam---tf-tree-errors/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

name="orange">  
^
You have a typo here inducing that your material isn't correctly defined. So when you use the material `orange` for the link `imu_link` you get an error and the link isn't created.

**Note :** When you have something wrong with an URDF file you can use tools like `check_urdf` that will tell you every mistakes/errors/typos.

---

**Edit :** The frame `odom` is actually published by your nodelet `ImuFilterNodelet`. From the [imu_filter_madgwick wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick#Parameters) :

```
~fixed_frame (string, default: odom)
The parent frame to be used in publish_tf.
~publish_tf (bool, default: true)
Whether to publish a TF transform that represents the orientation of the IMU, using the frame specified in fixed_frame as the parent frame and the frame given in the input imu message as the child frame.
```

Since you don't set those two parameters they are set to their default value, meaning that a frame `odom` is published and is set as the parent of the frame related to your imu messages (i.e. `imu_link` as defined when calling your other nodelet `PhidgetsImuNodelet`). So you end up with `imu_link` having `odom` as a parent from your nodelet AND `base_link` as a parent from the node `robot_state_publisher`, which explains why your tf tree is broken.

That being said, I'm not entirely sure about what you should do. You should see this [discussion](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_ros/issues/300).

You'll probably have to change your URDF to set `imu_link` as the parent of `base_link` instead of its child and then change the `tracking_frame` param from cartographer to the `base_link` (you shouldn't have removed the cartographer params from your previous update, they are part of your issue. Can you add them back please ?).

I hope that will help you.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-27**:
Hi, thanks. Sorry this is a copy paste error. I updated the code above, but unfortunately this does not resolve the issue.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
What is the issue ? I just used your urdf and `check_urdf` returns no errors and the robot is correctly displayed in Rviz with all the frames connected.

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-27**:
Hi, thanks you are completely right. I have updated the question/error accordingly.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
Thanks for the update, can you add a screenshot of your tf tree please ?

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-27**:
Hi, you can find the screenshots above.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
What is this `/imu_manager` broadcaster ? Is it the name you used when launching the `cartographer` node ? Also, since your frames `base_imu` and `base_link` are at the same pose and fixed, what happen if you set the param `tracking_frame` to `base_link` ?

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-27**:
Hi, thanks. Actually I thought the imu manager is called by the cartographer, however this is not true. I get the same problem if I only run the imu. I have updated the question...

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-28**:
The velocity filter of the imu package has been using a tf tree for the filtering. By only using the raw imu data the problem has been resolved. The cartographer map still doesn't work, [I opened a new question for this](https://bit.ly/2Tk7L7B). Thanks a lot for your help!